# bootstrap ui accordion not showing

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

I do not know what I have done wrong but the Accordion is just not showing up on my view (only a rectangular border).

This is the code:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Accordion -->
<div style="width:600px; margin:20px auto;">
<div ng-controller="AccordionCtrl">

<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
<uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ngrepeat="group in groups">
{{group.content}}
</uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
.controller('AccordionCtrl', function ($scope) {
// Add some content to accordion
$scope.groups = [
{
title: 'Header Content One',
content: 'Body Content One'
},
{
title: 'Header Content Two',
content: 'Body Content Two'
},
{
title: 'Header Content Three',
content: 'Body Content Three'
}
];
});
```